# Learning differential equations: a textbook

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, self-learning, mathematical-modeling

I am a Computational Biology master's student and I would like to study differential equations (both ODEs and PDEs).

I tried to have a look at the available textbooks but what I found is either too theory-oriented or too applications-oriented. I do not want to waste time proving theorems but I do not want to simply solve basic equations using finite differences.

The only text I found is *Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations* by Henner. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any review of it and it's quite huge. I also toke into consideration doing the ODE part by watching Gilbert Strang's short videos online and the PDE part watching some lectures on YouTube (*commutant*'s channel), but I was wondering whether this is too basic (MOOC style). Any suggestion?

Comment: It's hard to help you considering that what you think is 'too theory-oriented or too applications-oriented' probably isn't what I think is. Also, you need to understand both the theory and how to apply it in order to solve any problem you encounter. Are you specifically after analytical techniques to solve these kinds of problems? Or computational techniques?

Comment: @Mattos Well, if it is full of proofs, it's not what I am looking for. And usually there is a consensus of what is suitable for math students what for scientists. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Well have a look at Kreyszigs 'Advanced Engineering Mathematics' then, it might be what you're after.